# Get a Cloud Function name from the Cloud Function itself

Tags: google-cloud-functions, twilio, google-cloud-tasks

When sending SMS to Twilio, Twilio sends several requests to a specified URL to give a status of that SMS delivery through webhooks. I want to make this callback asynchronous, so I developed a Cloud Function that sends a representation of the request to a Cloud Task that itself reach a dedicated endpoint of my app that recreate and simulate the Twilio request internally.

Twilio signs his requests using:

- my twilio account's secret key
- **the absolute URL that it reaches out**
- and the body of his request

So on my backend, I should know which endpoint Twilio reached out initially. I want to do it inside the Cloud Function, and I want to do it programmatically because this "asynchronous webhook" is also used when people answers to SMS.

The current URL of my webhook has the following format:

```
https://<location>-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/<cloud function name>/<some SMS uuid>
```

The current payload sent to my Cloud Task is the following:

```
absoluteUri: req.protocol + '://' + req.hostname + req.originalUrl,
relativeUri: req.originalUrl,
queryParams: req.query,
headers: req.headers,
body: req.body,
```

The problem is that `req.originalUrl` do not contain the full URI, my `absoluteUri` is currently:

```
https://<location>-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/<some SMS uuid>
```

So here is my question: inside a Cloud Function, is there a way to get its name programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using python 3.9 and get the Cloud Function name from the curiously named "K_SERVICE" environment variable.

```
import os
print("Current Cloud Function Name {}".format(os.environ.get('K_SERVICE')))
```

Enjoy them while you can, Google are removing more and more useful environment variables with every new language version.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#python_37_and_go_111

Comment: Actually `K_SERVICE` is listed as being one of the few that remain in the _newer_ environments

Answer (score 0):

As the Cloud Function name is the entry point and should be hardcoded, I ended up writing a deploy script that sed some placeholder.

Looks very ugly, if you have a better way it will be welcome.